# Can I leave the Schengen area and go back if I receive an employee card?

Tags: long-stay-visas, czech-republic

I received a long-term visa to the Czech Republic (single entry) for employment purposes. I heard that the next step will be showing up at the Foreign Police within 3 days of arrival for biometric data collection. The process of issuing the employee card will commence, with anticipated collection time of around two weeks.

If I have a one-month gap after receiving the employee card until my starting date at my hiring company, will I be able to leave the Schengen area and go back without complications using only the employee card and my single-entry visa?

Comment: Once you have a residence permit issued by the Czech authorities, you can leave and re-enter the Schengen zone while it is valid.  You will have no more use for your visa.  I don't know whether the "employee card" is a residence permit (I suspect it is), and I don't know whether its period of validity will be tied to your employment start date (I suspect it will not).

Comment: Thanks for your help i found this on the ministry of interior website:
What is an employee card?

An employee card is a new type of permit for long-time residence in the territory of the Czech Republic (CR) where the purpose of the foreign national’ stay (longer than 3 months) is employment. A foreign national who has an employee card is entitled:

to reside in the territory of the CR and, at the same time,

to work in the job for which the employee card was issued, or